# WPF Changing menuitems style glyph from checkmark to radiobutton

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm dabbling with the menuitems glyph representation of the checkmark. I want to change the glyph from a checkmark to a radiobutton. How can I generate the glyph data for a radiobutton? or can I add a resource path to a radio button icon and how can I do this?

XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid Margin="-1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3D26A0DA" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="#FF212121" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: it doesn't have to be Path. place an Ellipse there

Comment: How are you expecting this to behave? If they're supposed to have radiobutton behavior and be mutually exclusive etc then you'll need to either write code or use a radiobutton.

Comment: @Andy I already have mutually exclusive radiobutton-like behavior but the icon is a checkmark. My final task is to change the checkmark to a radiobutton by changing the style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't have to be `Path` with Data. place an `Ellipse` there as a Glyph

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Grid Margin="-1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
            <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" 
                    BorderBrush="#FF26A0DA" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="11" 
                    ClipToBounds="False" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Height="16" Width="16" Margin="4">
                <Ellipse x:Name="Glyph" Fill="#FF212121" Visibility="Hidden"
                         FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="10" Width="10"/>
            </Border>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="2" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Glyph" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="#FF707070"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#0A000000"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#21000000"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

result:

[image: menu]

Comment: Thanks. Works great. I just want to make note that it appears GlyphPanel had to change also.